# PostgreSQL Trigger on inherited tables

Tags: postgresql, trigger

In my PostgreSQL I have a parent table and a number of child tables (inherited from the parent table).

How to create a trigger which will be bind to all the current and future child tables derived from the parent table?

In a nutshell, what should be at "xxx" in the following code to refer to all the child tables?

```
create trigger trigger1
after insert or update of a, b, c, d on xxx
for each row
execute procedure trigger_procedure1();
```

Comment: I've asked a moderator to move this to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thx. Sorry, I didn't know about dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database administration and fits better on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Table inheritance is a bit limited. In particular, you can't have a foreign key that references all parts of an inherited table set, and you can't define triggers or constraints that're inherited by a set of tables.

Comment: hmm. Sad :(
But when I am, lets say, inserting a row in my child table, the parent table is also getting updated (Actually they both are sharing the same data, I think there is no redundancy). Can I use this internal trigger (which is updating parent table) to activate my main trigger?

Comment: No you can't, because it's not an internal trigger, and it's not updating the parent table. Rather, it's doing the internal equivalent of a `union all` of all the tables when you SELECT from them. The data row only exists in one physical table. If you `SELECT * FROM ONLY the_parent_table` you'll see no rows from child tables for that reason.

Comment: ok.
So can you suggest me another approach?
I have n-number of clients. They own their respective tables. I want a trigger which will update a summary table (or lets say audit table), when there is an insertion in any one of those individual tables (These n-number of tables inherit one parent table). Thx a lot.

Comment: Create the trigger on each  child table. They can share the same trigger function.

Comment: hmm.... Thx a lot. I was thinking the same.